# is there a native php function to compare characters held in an array with a string?

Tags: php

i am searchgin for a function in php, or a very lightweight and short/easy way to find out if a set (array) of characters appear in a given array

```
if(chars_in_string(array("x","d","9", "Ã¼"), $anystring) ) do_something()
```

while x,d,9, Ã¼ are just as an example ... hmmm maybe i can solve this with regular expressions?

Comment: Do you want to know if they ALL appear or if ANY appear?

Comment: any ... returns true if one of them is in there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use strpbrk($string, implode(array("x","d","9", "Ã¼"))); 
:)

Comment: It just so happens I looked it up again recently because I needed it as well... It has a so-easy-to-remember name ;)

Comment: this is what i was looking for! thanks very much ;-) and really easy to remember.

Answer (score 4):

```
function all_chars_in_string($chars,$string) {
   foreach($chars as $char) {
      if (strpos($string,$char) === false) return false;
   }
   return true;
}

function any_chars_in_string($chars,$string) {
   foreach($chars as $char) {
      if (strpos($string,$char) !== false) return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: If you have an easier way, then show it for the benefit of others

Answer (score 0):

Looking if any char is in string

```
function anyCharInString($chars,$string) {
   foreach($chars as $chr)
      if (strpos($string,$chr) !== false) return true;
   return false;
}
```

Look if all chars are in the string

```
function allCharsInString($chars,$string) {
   foreach($chars as $chr)
      if (strpos($string,$chr) === false) return false;
   return true;
}
```

EDIT: I'm to slow.